# bash oneliner search for files and dump name and content into new file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

as title says I need to write a bash oneliner that finds all txt files and, for each, writes name and content into another file.
So far I wrote:

`find . -name "*.txt" -type f -exec cat {} + >> find_txt`

It works but now I don't know how to write the file name **before** its content. For example, given the following files

```
dirA/file1.txt
dirA/file2.txt
dirB/file3.txt
dirC/file4.txt
dirC/file5.txt
```

The oneliner should create `find_txt` file with the following content:

```
dirA/file1.txt
content of file1.txt
dirA/file2.txt
content of file2.txt
dirB/file3.txt
content of file3.txt
dirC/file4.txt
content of file4.txt
dirC/file5.txt
content of file5.txt
```

Any clue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `find . -name "*.txt" -type f -print -exec cat {} + >> find_txt`

Comment: @jordanm thanks for the suggestion but using `-print` it writes all filenames found at the top of the file and **then** the files' content, which is not what I need. I'm modifying the question because it's not clear.

Comment: Try `find . -name "*.txt" -type f -print -exec cat {} \; >> find_txt`

Comment: Yes now it's working, thanks a lot! You should reply to my question so then I can mark your answer as accepted.